# set text to textview if an image has been selected from gallery

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a textview: `Click to add an image` behind an imageview.

when user click, it will open the gallery. If user select an image it will be displayed in the imageview.

I want to set the textview text to blank if an image has been selected.

I tried inside imageview on click:

```
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        ImageViewText.setText("");
```

the problem here is the textview will be blank in the moment user click on the imageview. What I want is to reset it if user really selected an image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `startActivityForResult()`, you will get an image path `imageUri` from Intent in `onActivityResult()` method if an `image` selected successfully.

Add condition to Check `RESULT_OK` and `REQUEST_CODE`. If both `true` then set `image` to `imageView` and set `textView` value `blank("")` or change visibility to `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                // Set image 
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                // Set text
                textView.setText("");

                // Alternative
                // textView.setVisibility(View.GONE); or
                // textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: @RickJoe  My pleasure :) If my answer solves your problem properly then please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using startActivityForResult, you should have an onActivityResult method overridden. You can check there if the user has actually selected something which is where you can call setText("") or preferably setVisibility(View.GONE)